# how to remove an extra ',' from a json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a java map which I am converting into a json. This is how my script looks like

```
var newVar = '[';

for(var x in pdict.Stores){
    newVar += '{' + '"Store_ID":"' + x.ID + '",';
    newVar += '"inv list id":"' + x.inventoryList.ID + '",';
    newVar += '"Store Address":"' + x.address1 + '",';
    newVar += '"zip":"' + x.postalCode + '"},';
}

newVar += ']';
```

pdict.Stores is returning me a map. While doing the concatenation the last comma is getting added at the end of the json and the json is becoming invalid. How would I remove the last ',' before the closing of ']'

Here is the output

```
[{"Store_ID":"46305","inv list id":"jonesny-46305-inventory","Store Address":"739 Reading Avenue Suite #306","zip":"19610"},{"Store_ID":"48760","inv list id":"jonesny-46305-inventory","Store Address":"1665 State Hill Rd","zip":"19610"},{"Store_ID":"48811","inv list id":"jonesny-46305-inventory","Store Address":"1665 State Hill Road","zip":"19601"},{"Store_ID":"53046","inv list id":"jonesny-46305-inventory","Store Address":"2630 Westview Dr","zip":"19610"},]
```

I can not use jquery. It has to be oure javascript based solution.

Comment: Why aren't you building a regular Javascript object then calling `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: @joe--can you post some example?

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that.

Create a new object, build it out, and serialize it with `stringify`.

```
var a = [];
for(var x in pdict.Stores){
    var b = {};
    b.Store_ID = x.id;
    b["inv list id"] = x.inventoryList.ID;
    b["Store Address"] = x.address1;
    b.zip = x.postalCode;
    a.push(b);
}

return JSON.stringify(a);
```

Comment: @Joe-- I am getting null when I am checking the length of the a